Pull requests using the Azure DevOps plugin in JetBrains Rider
I have installed the Azure DevOps plugin for Rider on macOS, and I am trying to create a pull request from my local branch into the remote master branch up on DevOps. I was able to authenticate and clone the repo from the Open from Version Control dialog, and I can push to the upstream branch directly, but I can't find anything about creating a pull request.
I've looked in View -> Tool Windows as well as the whole Git menu, including the Push dialog, but nothing. The plugin is enabled and properly authenticated. Any insight as to what's going on?

Also asked on DevOps Stack Exchange

I test the Azure DevOps plugin for Rider on Windows (I don't have a MacOS agent).
I found that I can search the keyword pull request to find the option to create a pull request. Please try to search "Pull request" and see if it works on MacOS.
My steps:

Search the keyword pull request.


Click the  and create a pull request. It will show a Tip that the Pull request is created.


Click the Tip to navigate to the pull request page



Update

I wonder where that option is actually located.

I searched "pull request" in the settings and found it should be located in Main Menu > Git > VCS Group > Git. But I didn't find it in the Main Menu.

Then in the settings > Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars, I found the option is located in "Vcs.MainMenu", but in the Main Menus's Git is shows options in "Git.MainMenu".
Luckly, I found we can Customize menus and toolbars. So, I added the "create a pull request" to "Git.MainMenu".

Now, I can see the "create a pull request" in the Main Menus > Git.


Do you know if it's possible to link it to work items?

Yes, you can add the #ID in the description to link work items to the pull request.


Thank you! I wonder where that option is actually located. Do you know if it's possible to link it to work items?

Hi @AAM111, I found the option location and yes, we can link PR to work items. Please check the update part in my answer.

Thanks so much for the help. What a terrible plugin - I expected better from Microsoft.

I started seeing a new pull request tab in git window. Press Alt + 9 to view Version Control window.
pull request tab

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
